# Delphi VCL Fastreport Generate a huge JPG to replace the function of PS template nesting

Tags: delphi, vcl, fastreport

I want to use Fastreport to generate a huge jpg.

Similar to Photoshop to generate 300dpi poster template.

But I found that if I want to get the resolution that can be printed directly,

When using huge JPG on the background of page, the program will be very slow.

Some low configured machines will overflow memory.

Does the expert know what to do?

[image]